# How can I plot the horizontal grid according the y-axis ticks in D3?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I'm having difficulty to plot the horizontal grid according the y-axis tick values. I'm able to plot the grid on y-axis but it's not coming according the Y-axis co-ordinates.

[Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8ePb.png)

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mohit_Agrawal/4S3Gq/89/)

```
var data = [["Since Mar 10, 2015",150], ["1 year",-17.1], ["3 year",6.9],["Since Mar 10, 2010",100]];


d3.select("#example")
 .datum(data)
 .call(columnChart()
 .width(320)
 .height(240)
 .x(function(d, i) { return d[0]; })
 .y(function(d, i) { return d[1]; }));

function columnChart() {
 var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
  width = 20,
  height = 20,
  xRoundBands = 0.6,
  xValue = function(d) { return d[0]; },
  yValue = function(d) { return d[1]; },
  xScale = d3.scale.ordinal(),
  yScale = d3.scale.linear(),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left"),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);
  var isNegative = false;    

 function chart(selection) {
  selection.each(function(data) {

  // Convert data to standard representation greedily;
  // this is needed for nondeterministic accessors.
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
     if(data[i][1] < 0){
       isNegative = true;
    }
  }  

  data = data.map(function(d, i) {
    return [xValue.call(data, d, i), yValue.call(data, d, i)];
  });

  // Update the x-scale.
  xScale
      .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[0];} ))
      .rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right], xRoundBands);


  // Update the y-scale.
  yScale
      .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d[1];} )))
      .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
      .nice();


  // Select the svg element, if it exists.
  var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

  // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
  var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
  gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "bars");
  gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");
  gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
  gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis zero");

  // Update the outer dimensions.
  svg .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // Update the inner dimensions.
  var g = svg.select("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 // Update the bars.
  var bar = svg.select(".bars").selectAll(".bar").data(data);
  bar.enter().append("rect");
  bar.exit().remove();
  bar .attr("class", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? "bar negative" : "bar positive"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return X(d); })
      .attr("y", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? Y0() : Y(d); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function(d, i) { return Math.abs( Y(d) - Y0() ); });

// x axis at the bottom of the chart
if( isNegative === true ){
   var xScaleHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom+12;
}else{
    var xScaleHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
}        
 g.select(".x.axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + ( xScaleHeight ) + ")")
    .call(xAxis.orient("bottom"))
    .selectAll("text")
    .call(wrap, xScale.rangeBand());

// zero line
 g.select(".x.axis.zero")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + Y0() + ")")
    .attr("class", "zero axis")
    .call(xAxis.tickFormat("").tickSize(0));


   // Update the text in bars.
   var bar1 = svg.select(".bars").selectAll("text").data(data);

   bar1 .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr("class", "text")
       .text(function(d) { return d[1]+"%"; })
       .attr("x", function(d) { return X(d); })
       .attr("y", function(d, i) { return d[1] < 0 ? Math.abs(Y(d)+10) : Y(d)-2; });

    // Update the y-axis.
     g.select(".y.axis")
        //.call(yAxis)
        .call(yAxis.tickSize(3).ticks(5))
        .selectAll("g")
        .selectAll("text")
        .text(function(d){
            return d+"%";
        });

  // Horizontal grid
  g.insert("g", ".bars")         
    .attr("class", "grid horizontal")

    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .tickSize(-(height), 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
     );
 });
```

}

```
 // Custom function for text wrap
  function wrap(text, width) {
     text.each(function() {
     var text = d3.select(this),
     words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
     word,
     line = [],
     lineNumber = 0,
     lineHeight = 1, // ems
     y = text.attr("y"),
     dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
     tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
   while (word = words.pop()) {
    line.push(word);
    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
    if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > 55) {
      line.pop();
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      line = [word];
      tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
   }
  }
});
}


// The x-accessor for the path generator; xScale ∘ xValue.
function X(d) {
  return xScale(d[0]);
}

function Y0() {
  return yScale(0);
}

// The x-accessor for the path generator; yScale ∘ yValue.
function Y(d) {
 return yScale(d[1]);
}

chart.margin = function(_) {
  if (!arguments.length) return margin;
   margin = _;
   return chart;
 };

  chart.width = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length) return width;
   width = _;
   return chart;
 };

 chart.height = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length) return height;
   height = _;
   return chart;
  };

 chart.x = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
   xValue = _;
   return chart;
 };

 chart.y = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
    yValue = _;
    return chart;
  };

 return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

Instead of your code to generate horizontal grid

```
// Horizontal grid
  g.insert("g", ".bars")         
    .attr("class", "grid horizontal")

    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .tickSize(-(height), 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")
     );
 });
```

Add this it will iterate through the ticks `.data(yScale.ticks(5))`

```
    g.append("g").selectAll("line.line").data(yScale.ticks(5)).enter()
.append("line")
    .attr(
    {
        "class":"line grid tick",
        "x1" : margin.right,
        "x2" : width,
        "y1" : function(d){ return yScale(d);},
        "y2" : function(d){ return yScale(d);},
    });
});
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/fjuak9bo/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Cyril for your reply but you can see the horizontal grid is coming on top of the bar. I want that grid comes behind the chart bars. I also tried some css properties but not working. :(

Comment: check this you have to draw the grid before the bar chart to show it behind http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/fjuak9bo/3/